# How can I set ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs in service or data access layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm using an `ObjectDataSource` to perform the CRUD operations on a `GridView`.  When an item is being removed, I want to be able to make sure no foreign key constraints are being violated, and if so, display a message to the user in the presentation layer by using the `ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs` in the `ObjectDataSource Deleted` function:

```
protected void ods_Deleted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        // Display message that was set in either the service or data access layer
    }
}
```

I figure the constraint can be checked in either the service layer or the data access layer.

**Service layer**

```
// This is the DeleteMethod used by the ObjectDataSource
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)]
public virtual bool Remove(Entity entity)
{
    bool CanDelete = functionToSeeIfAnythingIsUsingThisKey(entity.ID);
    if (CanDelete)
    {
        _repository.Remove(entity);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // would like to populate ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs that are sent
        // back to the ObjectDataSource onDeleted function in Presentation layer
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Data Access Layer**

```
public virtual void Remove(Entity entity)
{
    _session = NHibernateSessionProvider.GetSession();
    try
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _session.Delete(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // database will throw an error if the constraint check fails,
        // which is caught here
    }
}
```

I know that whatever is returned from the service layer function can be seen in `e.ReturnValue` once back to the presentation layer, but is it possible to set the other members of `ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs` (ie, AffectedRows, Exception, OutputParemters, etc)?